Why does GitHub Actions have asterisks *** in an ENV dump?
When I dump the environmental with a job that executes env, I see
BOOTSTRAP_HASKELL_NONINTERACTIVE=1
***
PIPX_BIN_DIR=/opt/pipx_bin

That *** is PWD=/home/runner/work/ec-test-repo/ec-test-repo why would GitHub block that out?

It's a silly check that fouls SecretUtility.cs which blacklists PWD= and removes it subsequently in ScrubTraditionalSecrets.
